# Putty highlighting copying

Tags: command-line, 14.04, putty

I currently use Putty at my work and I am always fascinating by how useful the highlight copying tool is. Is there any kind of program I can download on my System 76 laptop that I can use when I am in the terminal that will allow the same feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the text you want to copy, then you can paste it anywhere by clicking on the mousewheel.

Comment: I am looking for something more automated where the highlight can automatically copy the text just like in Putty

Comment: It does automaticly copy it. The buffer it uses is just a different one than the strg+c buffer. Just paste it with middle-click.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste by following method for terminal:

1. Select/Highlight text and **Middle-Click** mouse button to paste it in **Terminal** or somewhere else in Ubuntu.
2. Select text and copy by (i) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from another app (ii) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> **from Terminal** and Paste by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> **into terminal**.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a way to highlight text that will copy it to the buffer and allow me to paste using the mouse instead of the keyboard.